# Making an intranet url available externally?

Tags: windows, vpn

At the moment I have a client that has an intranet set up on their internal network. This server isn't accessible unless via VPN.

The problem is that they have an RSS feed on the intranet that they'd like to make publicly available. I'm wondering what the necessary steps would be (on a windows server) to make this RSS feed available to the external network?

Since we have an external web server hosting all of their public sites, I was wondering if setting up a VPN on that machine would be a possibility? That way I could connect to the internal network, pick up the required RSS feed and then feed that through to the web server and broadcast that publicly?

What are my options here?

Comment: It's called reverse proxy, done on the public server.

Comment: `if setting up a VPN on that machine would be a possibility?` ---> Well, it depends on who own the hosting. If you are owner then you can get VPN, otherwise there is little possibility that your hosting provider to their server...

Comment: Yes we own the hosting. I'm just trying to find out my options and see which is the most sensible.